# Trim image background but leave padding in Graphicsmagick

Tags: php, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I assemble Graphicsmagick commands in php and then call them using exec(). I need to trim images but retain a padding of 20 pixels. So I want to do the following:

```
exec('gm convert input.jpg -trim -bordercolor white -border 20x20 output.jpg');
```

but use the color which was trimmed instead of white. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
gm convert input.jpg -crop 1x1+0+0 corner.txt
color=`sed -e "s/.* #/#/" corner.txt`
gm convert input.jpg -trim -bordercolor $color -border 20x20 output.jpg
```

The txt format in GraphicsMagick has no header (unlike ImageMagick) so the (0,0) pixel is in the first line (actually the only line of a 1x1 image).
The corner.txt file for the 1x1 cropped image is simply this:

```
0,0: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF
```

It happened to be white in my test image, but it will be whatever the color of the (0,0) pixel.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also found the [fuzz](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-fuzz) parameter really helpful, which lets you trim edges even if you have a crappy jpeg with artifacts around the edges.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is currently not possible with GraphicsMagick (at the time of this writing: GM v1.4 beta).

In ImageMagick it can be done because IM provides an fx command to sample the color value of a given pixel:

```
convert myimage.png -format '%[fx:p{10,20}]' info:
```

This will return the color value of the pixel at position x=10, y=20. The output can then be used in subsequent IM commands to add a border of that color.